# Issue with Eloquent Relationships in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an issue using Eloquent ORM in Laravel 4.2

I have 2 tables, banks and bank_accounts

In banks i have the ID of the bank and in the bank_accounts table i have bank_id and it's foreign key pointing to banks table.

I have been struggling with this for hours and looking in the Laravel Documentation without any luck.

I have two models:

BankAccounts Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class Cuentas extends Eloquent 
    {
      protected $table      = 'icar_cuentas';
      protected $primaryKey = 'id';  
      public    $timestamps = FALSE;

      public function Banco()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo('Bancos','id_banco');
      }
    }
```

Banks Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Bancos extends Eloquent 
{
  protected $table      = 'icar_bancos';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';  
  public    $timestamps = FALSE;

  public function cuentasRelacionadas()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Cuentas');
  }
}
```

What i need is to list the accounts added by the user and show the name of its related bank but didn't figured out how to do it.

So far i have in the Controller:

```
public function showCuentas()
  {
    $results = Cuentas::all();

    return View::make('content.bancos.list_bancos', array('bancos' => $results));
  }
```

And the View:

```
<tbody>
            @foreach($bancos as $banco)
                          @if($banco->activo == 'si')
                             {{-- */$estado = '<span class="label label-success">Activo</span>';/* --}}
                          @endif
                          @if($banco->activo == 'no')
                             {{-- */$estado = '<span class="label label-danger">Inactivo</span>';/* --}}
                          @endif
              <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ URL::to('cuentas/editar/'.Encryption::encode($banco->id)) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> | <a href="{{ URL::to('cuentas/eliminar'.Encryption::encode($banco->id)) }}" onclick="return confirma('Realmente deseas eliminar la cuenta {{ $banco->cuenta }}');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                <td>{{ $banco->banco->first()->banco }}</td>
                <td>{{ $banco->cuenta }}</td>
                <td>{{ $banco->tipo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $estado }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

But it always shows the name of the First Bank in the table instead of the related one.

Appreciate any help

Comment: `$banco->banco->first()->banco` ? Why is this here?

Comment: I use the $banco as object, then ->banco as the method inside the model following the ->first() to get the first record (and only) that matches the bank_id and the ->banco at the end is the field in the table containing the name of the bank

Comment: Try `{{ $banco->banco->banco }}` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use lazy loading, because, for each `Cuenta` you will have another query in your database. Use eager loading instead:

```
$results = Cuentas::with('banco')->get();
```

Then you go:

```
foreach($bancos as $banco) { //--> I think you should replace with cuentas, but it's up to you
    ....
    {{ $banco->banco->banco }} // also, terrible. Use banco.name instead. Give proper name to easily understand your code
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i though that i could simplify the query (That's why using Eloquent instead of Query Builder) but didn't managed to get to this. It's working now, i already accepted your answer and gave you feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: I somehow didn't see your answer. Could save my time writing almost the same (except of eager loading).

Answer (score 0):

well, the doc say for the method Model::belongsTo (laravel 4.2)

```
belongsTo( string $related, string $foreignKey = null, string $otherKey = null, string $relation = null)
```

i see the second argument you pass to your function Cuentas::belongsTo()  is 'id_cuentos'
But in class Bancos the primary key attribute say the name of the primary key is 'id'.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

isn't there something wrong about it ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it didn't worked. Still shows the first record of the table instead of the related one

Comment: The second argument for `belongsTo()` is the name of the foreign key column - not the name of the targets table primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

The `public function Banco()` is a `belongsTo` relation and will return a `Bancos` object - not a collection of them. So when you call `->fist()` on that object it's not the `Collection::fist()` function - it is `Bancos::first()`. That is the reason why you allways get the first entry from Bancos model.

In your foreach loop `$banco` is a Cuentas object. And `$banco->banco` is the related Bancos object that you need. So if you have an attribute `$banco` in your `Bancos` object - all you need to call in your template is

```
{{ $banco->banco->banco }}
```

As others mentioned in their answers, you should either rename `Banco()` to `banco()` or call `{{ $banco->Banco->banco }}`.

As a side note: Your naming style is very confusing. Why do you call a `Cuentas` collection `$bancos`?

I would rename some things:

- `function Banco()` => `function banco()`
- `array('bancos' => $results)` => `array('cuentas' => $results)`
- `@foreach($bancos as $banco)` => `@foreach($cuentas as $cuenta)`
- `{{ $banco->banco->banco }}` => `{{ $cuenta->banco->banco }}`

Additionally (if possible) i would rename the attribute `Bancos::banco` to `Bancos::name` so you can call `{{ $cuenta->banco->name }}` without confusing the reviewers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure things are case sensitive and you are using Banco in the model and banco in the view.

Comment: Is not that, if you see the code i call the Model by doing Bancos::all() then in my view i get the object $banco and summon the ->banco method from the model